# Criteria for approving an edit on Politics SE

Tags: discussion

I am wondering about the criteria for selecting or rejecting an edit. For example, with the following post:

https://politics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7392

One person voted to reject and one to accept, but overall the edit was rejected. My feeling from my postings on Stack Exchange in general and particularly Stack Overflow (where I have most edits) was usually it took some sort of consensus to accept or reject an edit, and that when this was not the case the edit was marked as 'disputed'. Is that not the case here? Or is my perception of the Stack Exchange/Politics SE algorithms overly simplistic in this case perhaps?

What are the criteria by which an edit is accepted or rejected on Politics SE (and is this perhaps different for different types of edit)?

Comment: The reject was by a diamond. Not sure, but it may be binding the same way a VTC/VTRO by a diamond is binding (meaning, it has the effect of counting as as-many-votes-as-needed from regular voters; up to 5 in case of questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- When 3 people vote reject, it is rejected.
- When 3 people vote accept it is accepted.
- For questions and answers, only takes 1 vote from the OP to accept or reject.
- It only takes 1 vote from a diamond moderator to accept or reject.

Your edit was rejected by a diamond moderator.

Comment: The diamond and the pyramid.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's only two, not three.  [Example](http://politics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7370).

Comment: @Brythan That could be the case.  It's 3 at stack overflow, but other SEs do have different settings for things